# How to render DIV tag only on desktop devices (width > 1024)

Tags: javascript, html, performance

How to render DIV tag only on desktop devices (width > 1024px)

I don't want to use CSS display:none
because elements still loading while using CSS

Could be done with a javascript to render DIV tag over desktop devices

```
<div class="desktop">

    <h1> Test </h1>
    <p> Hello World this content load only for desktop devices </p>
    <img src="test.png" width="100" height="100">

</div>
```

Comment: Do you not want to load all elements to save on bandwidth and speed? If its images you're looking to offload, you could use a good image lazyload script, i.e. one that only loads images when they're displayed and in the viewport? Trying to put all the HTML into JS will get messy.

Comment: You can use media queries in JavaScript i.e. `if(window.matchMedia('min-width:1024px').matches){
 //do something
}` However I totally agree with @UnbrandedManchester

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
<script>
    var screen_width = screen.width;
    if(screen_width<1024){
        document.querySelector(".desktop").remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This would work if you are hiding just for UI Improvements. But if you mean to increase performance and loading time, I suggest lazy loading.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you.